# Question about using Montgomery form for elliptic curve operations on bls12-381

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, montgomery-multiplication

Since the prime for bls12-381 is not of a form to allow easy modular reduction , is the best approach to use the Montgomery multiplication + reduction algorithm?

`(q = 0x1a0111ea397fe69a4b1ba7b6434bacd764774b84f38512bf6730d2a0f6b0f6241eabfffeb153ffffb9feffffffffaaab)`

If I do this, can I convert the affine point coordinates into jacobian projected and then into their Montgomery form at the very start, so all modulo multiplications inside the point double / add algorithms use the Montgomery algorithm? Then only convert out of Montgomery form and then back to affine coordinates at the very end.

Comment: Unless there's some special structure you can exploit in $q$ (and if there is, it's not obvious to me), Montgomery form is a reasonable choice, with a Barrett reduction to kick it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, the best approach is to use either Montgomery or Barrets algorithm for modulo reduction, Barrets requires a slightly higher bit multiplication but not pre-transformation, while Montgomery has a pre-transformation but multiplications are slightly faster.

And if you use Montgomery you can do the entire point double/add in Montgomery form using jacobian coordinates and just convert back at the end.